# C: How to obtain a list of files in Windows directory?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, file, ftp

I am trying to implement an FTP Server in C (school assignment), according to the RFC959 standard.

I am having trouble with the LIST command. The RFC reads:
"This command causes a list to be sent from the server to the
passive DTP.  If the pathname specifies a directory or other
group of files, the server should transfer a list of files
in the specified directory.  If the pathname specifies a
file then the server should send current information on the
file.  A null argument implies the user's current working or
default directory."

I know that there are functions like GetCurrentDirectory, etc. Is there a function to obtain an ouput such as that of 'dir' in MS-DOS command prompt? Anything just similiar would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Answer (score 4):

[`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) & `FindNextFile` are the APIs to enumerate a path.

Answer (score 1):

Adrian Worley wrote a tutorial explaining how to get a list of files in a directory using FindFirstFile and FindNextFile
http://www.adrianxw.dk/SoftwareSite/FindFirstFile/FindFirstFile1.html

Here's a small example.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;

    cout << "FindFirstFile/FindNextFile demo.\n" << endl;

    // Find the first file

    hFind = FindFirstFile("C:\\Windows\\*.exe", &FindData);
    cout << FindData.cFileName << endl;

    // Look for more

    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData))
    {
        cout << FindData.cFileName << endl;
    }

    // Close the file handle

    FindClose(hFind);

    return 0;
}
```