# filename completion with C++

Tags: c++, windows

In python, if you want to open all the files that started with "apl_" you can simply open "apl*". How do you do something similar in C++.

Say I have a file which I know starts with "llll", but have unknown suffixes. How do I open it?

Comment: It might not be the best way, but one method could be to iterate through them with `boost::filesystem`, check if `name.find ("llll") == name.begin()`, and open the ones that satisfy the condition.

Comment: No, you can't do that in Python. Of course there are other ways to do it—but open("api*") will raise an IOError (unless you actually have a file called "api*")

Comment: @abarnert: Check out the `glob.glob()` function: `open(glob.glob('apl_*')[0], 'r')`

Comment: @Blender: Yes, but that's not the same as "simply opening". You can also call _glob or FindFirstFile/FindNextFile from C or C++ on Windows, which is the nearest equivalent to glob.glob in Python.

Comment: @abarnert: Post that as an answer ;) That's what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that's what the OP is trying to do. I suspect he's actually calling his Python script with api* on the command line and cmd is expanding it for him, in which case the exact same thing will work in C++…

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the directory
2. Step through the list of files in the directory
3. Open the files whose names match your pattern.

[C: How to obtain a list of files in Windows directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295156/c-how-to-obtain-a-list-of-files-in-windows-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just 'simply open "apl*"' in Python. If you try this:

```
open("apl*")
```

You will get an IOError—unless you happen to have a file literally named "apl*".

There are two basic ways to do this in Python, both of which can be translated to C++.

First:

```
[open(f) for f in glob.glob("apl*")]
```

On most non-Windows platforms, `glob.glob` translates directly into the POSIX function `glob`. Unfortunately, on Windows, it's called `_glob`, doesn't exist on all versions of Windows, and has severe limitations. So, instead, you want to use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The examples given on the linked pages should show you how to do it.

Second:

```
[open(f) for f in os.listdir(".") if f.startswith("apl")]
```

You can again do this by just using FindFirstFile/FindNextFile to iterate the entire directory, and then filter on whether data->cFileName starts with "apl", but you might as well use much cleaner (and more portable) boost::filesystem::directory_iterator.